# .split(",") every 4th item only?

Tags: javascript

I started with a string:

```
hidden = "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h";
```

I then split(",") the string into something I can try to work with:

```
array = hidden.split(",");
```

If I console.log out, the result is:

```
["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]
```

What I would eventually like to end up with (using JS only) is:

```
["a,b,c,d","e,f,g,h"];
```

or

```
[["a,b,c,d"],["e,f,g,h"]];
```

Thanks!

EDIT to show that I am actually trying to figure this out (don't mind the formatting):

```
if (currentPage === "view-bills.php")
{
var str = "";
hidden = document.getElementById("billItems");
array = hidden.value.split(",");
for (var i=0;i<array.length;i++)
{
str += "<option>"+ array[i] +"</option>";
}
var itemsAmt = document.getElementById("items").value;
document.getElementById("displayItems").innerHTML = "<optgroup label='"+ itemsAmt +" items'>" + str + "</optgroup>";
}
```

**UPDATE:**

The problem has been solved, however, I would like to show you the outcome of my project (accessing classes instead of id's this time):

[http://i.imgur.com/umjhGPP.png](https://i.imgur.com/umjhGPP.png)
[image: ProjectResults]

Once again, don't mind my formatting, I have trouble pasting things in here:

```
if (currentPage === "view-bills.php")
{
// Add items to select box
hidden = document.getElementsByClassName("billItems");
for (var n=0;n<hidden.length;n++)
{
array = hidden[n].value.split(",");
groups = [];
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i+=5)
{
groups.push(array.slice(i,i+5).join(','))
}
var str = "";
for (var j=0;j<groups.length;j++)
{
str += "<option>"+ groups[j] +"</option>";
}
var itemsAmt = document.getElementsByClassName("items")[n].value;
document.getElementsByClassName("displayItems")[n].innerHTML = "<optgroup label='"+ itemsAmt +" items'>" + str + "</optgroup>";
}
}
```

Comment: 2 downvotes, why? it's a good question.

Comment: @djechlin _this question does not show any research effort._ (I can see how this one is on the fence; this one feels too "gimme the code" for my taste.)

Comment: @Mathletics it should be upvoted. I've already put enough research effort into doing this that I would rather there have been a solution on StackOverflow by now. Which there could be, if...  this gets answered.

Comment: In fact, if this were *my* question, I would have posted it before researching, then self-answered if I figured it out whether in 5 minutes or 30.

Comment: This is going to become a meta-conversation about what SO is or is not. I stand by my downvote; the beauty of the community is that any/all are welcome to disagree and vote accordingly.

Comment: I figured it would be easier to summarize my question to avoid causing confusion for others trying to read through a page of code, I don't see why that's a problem.

Comment: @Scott none of the code you posted is relevant to the problem though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternate way with a simple loop;

```
hidden = "a,b,c,d,e,f,g";
arr = hidden.split(",");
groups = []

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i+=4)
  groups.push(arr.slice(i,i+4).join(','))

console.log(groups)

> [ 'a,b,c,d', 'e,f,g' ]
```

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit Works with 'h' too, just demonstrating that it doesn't need even 4-groups.

Comment: For OP's sake you may want to initialize `groups`.

Comment: @Mathletics Thanks, missed that :)

Comment: This is the best answer in terms of complexity and readability.

Comment: Sorry to say, but a regex match is more readable, shorter and faster [see jsperf](http://jsperf.com/group-split-vs-match)

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit I hope you didn't downvote based on that. They're both well over 1M ops/s (and I strongly disagree re:readability) so you're _really_ splitting hairs here.

Comment: Needing to join part that have just been split doesn't feel right to me. It's misleading, thus less readable too me. Try to do that with a cake, it won't work :)

Comment: It does feel weird when you put it like that, but in order to get the parts to act as an array to begin with (before it was a string), I had to split them. So the split creates the array, then we join the parts of the array that we want. Not entirely misleading. I have to try that with cake, I'm curious now.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a regular expression:

```
var hidden = "aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee,fff,ggg,hhh,iii";
console.log(hidden.match(/(([^,]+,){0,3}[^,]+)/g));
```

**Output**

```
["aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd", "eee,fff,ggg,hhh", "iii"]
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gt5u55pz/)

Comment: @djechlin maybe you'd like to share them?

Comment: @Mathletics regexes are hard to write (evidenced by the bug) and hard to read (evidenced by 5 upvotes before someone found a bug). I don't think throwing out a test case is going to produce a higher quality solution.

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit alternate regex `/([^,](,*.){3})/g` http://jsfiddle.net/aLwc5vdh/2/ (treat the comma like an optional prefix)

Comment: @djechlin minor bug fixed

Comment: @Mathletics your regex doesn't work if only 1 additional item

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit yes, I noticed that. Thanks for fixing it!

Comment: This works when it comes to splitting the entire string, which would actually be the answer to my question; however, in my example a,b,c,d (and so on) were just placeholders for dynamic length strings, e.g.: 123,abcde,batm4n,kfc55.

Answer (score 0):

This code takes the split version of the data and then groups it into groups of 4.

If there aren't exactly four items in the last group, it adds it after the for loop.

You could reduce repetition by extracting the `join` logic into a simple function so you aren't repeating the code (you would have to change both lines if you wanted to join with a different character, for example). I have kept the example rather procedural so you can get the general idea.

```
var hidden = "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h";

var allItems = hidden.split(',');

var groups = [];
var currentGroup = [];

for (var i = 0; i < allItems.length; i++) {
    currentGroup.push(allItems[i]);

    if (currentGroup.length === 4) {
        groups.push(currentGroup.join(','));
        currentGroup = [];
    }
}

if (currentGroup.length > 0) {
    groups.push(currentGroup.join(','));
}

console.log(groups);
```

Result:

```
[ "a,b,c,d", "e,f,g,h" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it in a reduce e.g. [via lodash](http://lodash.com/doc#reduce):

```
return _.reduce(hidden.split(','), function(result, value, key) {
    if(key % 4 === 0) result.push("");
    result[result.length - 1] += value;
    return result;
}, []);
```

I think this is about the simplest solution you'll find, given the necessity of the chunk-every-fourth step.

Comment: @Mathletics uh, dude, some people come to this page who are actually using said external library. They would like to know to use that solution. There certainly shouldn't be a duplicate of this question with the words "using lodash?" or "permitting external libraries?" attached. I'm not saying it should be the accepted answer (unless the OP is using node.js or something, in which case maybe!) but it should be available to readers.

Comment: then leave it up _dude_, you can spare the rep.

Comment: @Mathletics honestly, you probably enjoyed that downvote more than I did answering this question. I'm done answering questions here. Deleting my account in a few days.

Comment: @AAA downvotes happen, don't delete your account for that. You seem to have a good reputation. But your answer here isn't the simplest solution :)

Comment: Couple of things. First, you might want to indicate that using `Array#reduce` is also a possibility, for newbies who might not be able to see that for themselves, or those who don't know the meaning of "e.g." Second, this doesn't work, since you need to **return** result.

Answer (score -3):

So far I've just found the obvious loop:

```
var array = hidden.split(",");
var result = [];
for(var i = 0; i + 3 < array.length; i += 3) {
    result.push("" + array[i] + array[i+1] + array[i+2] + array[i+3]) + ",";
}
if(i < array.length) {
    var last = "";
    for(; i < array.length; i++) {
        last += array[i];
    }
    array.push(last);
}
```